# jQuery Tetris app, problem with game ending

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a Tetris app on JavaScript + jQuery and came across a tricky bug.

In some cases, the app is alerting 'Game is over' even when the blocks are on the bottom of the playfield.

Here is a short explanation of my algorithm:

- all blocks are spawning at a particular place (tetris.origin = {row: 2, col: 5})
- all blocks have a `bgcolor` attribute - "red"; when the block is coming across another block, a `bgcolor` is changing to "RED" - this is how blocks freeze
- I wrote a function that took a look at the very first row: `if (row === 0 and (bgcolor === RED)` - it should show the gameover message

Did I make a mistake in my gameIsOver function? Or I should rewrite my spawn function too?

A link to the Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/leocete/pen/eXzJxM)

**My index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Tetris-app</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id='playfield'></table>

    <script src="src/tetris.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Tetris.js**

```
let tetris = {};

// Variable to store current coordinates
tetris.origin = {row: 2, col: 5};
tetris.currentShape;
tetris.currentCoordinates;

// Drawing the grid (playfield)
tetris.drawPlayField = function() {
    for (let row = 0; row < 22; row++) {
        $('#playfield').append('<tr class="'+row+'"></tr>');
        for (let col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
            $('tr.'+row).append('<td id="'+col+'"></td>');
        }
    }
}

// Drawing different shapes
tetris.shapeToCoordinates = function(shape, origin) {
    if (shape === 'L') {
        return [
            {row:origin.row,col:origin.col},
            {row:origin.row-1,col:origin.col},
            {row:origin.row+1,col:origin.col},
            {row:origin.row+1,col:origin.col+1}
        ];
    } else if (shape === 'I') {
        return [
            {row: origin.row, col: origin.col},
            {row: origin.row - 1, col: origin.col},
            {row: origin.row - 2, col: origin.col},
            {row: origin.row + 1, col: origin.col},
        ]
    } else if (shape === 'J') {
        return [
            {row: origin.row, col: origin.col},
            {row: origin.row - 1, col: origin.col},
            {row: origin.row + 1, col: origin.col},
            {row: origin.row + 1, col: origin.col - 1}
        ];
    } else if (shape === 'O') {
        return [
            {row: origin.row, col: origin.col},
            {row: origin.row + 1, col: origin.col},
            {row: origin.row, col: origin.col + 1},
            {row: origin.row + 1, col: origin.col + 1}
        ];
    } else if (shape === 'S') {
        return [
            {row:origin.row,col:origin.col},
            {row:origin.row-1,col:origin.col},
            {row:origin.row,col:origin.col-1},
            {row:origin.row-1,col:origin.col+1}
        ];
    } else if (shape === 'T') {
        return [
            {row:origin.row,col:origin.col},
            {row:origin.row-1,col:origin.col},
            {row:origin.row,col:origin.col-1},
            {row:origin.row,col:origin.col+1}
        ];
    } else if (shape === 'Z') {
        return [
            {row:origin.row,col:origin.col},
            {row:origin.row-1,col:origin.col},
            {row:origin.row-1,col:origin.col-1},
            {row:origin.row,col:origin.col+1}
        ];
    } else if (shape ==='L90') {
        return [
            {row:origin.row,col:origin.col},
            {row:origin.row,col:origin.col+1},
            {row:origin.row,col:origin.col-1},
            {row:origin.row+1,col:origin.col-1}
        ]
    } else if (shape === 'L90') {
        return [
            {row:origin.row,col:origin.col},
            {row:origin.row,col:origin.col+1},
            {row:origin.row,col:origin.col-1},
            {row:origin.row+1,col:origin.col-1}
        ];
    } else if (shape === 'L180') {
        return [
            {row:origin.row,col:origin.col},
            {row:origin.row-1,col:origin.col},
            {row:origin.row+1,col:origin.col},
            {row:origin.row-1,col:origin.col-1}
        ];
    } else if (shape === 'L270') {
        return [
            {row:origin.row,col:origin.col},
            {row:origin.row,col:origin.col+1},
            {row:origin.row,col:origin.col-1},
            {row:origin.row-1,col:origin.col+1}
        ];
    } else if (shape === 'J90') { 
          return [
              {row:origin.row,col:origin.col},
              {row:origin.row,col:origin.col-1},
              {row:origin.row,col:origin.col+1},
              {row:origin.row-1,col:origin.col-1}
            ];
      } else if (shape === 'J180') { 
          return [
              {row:origin.row,col:origin.col},
              {row:origin.row-1,col:origin.col},
              {row:origin.row+1,col:origin.col},
              {row:origin.row-1,col:origin.col+1}
            ];
      } else if (shape === 'J270') { 
          return [
              {row:origin.row,col:origin.col},
              {row:origin.row,col:origin.col-1},
              {row:origin.row,col:origin.col+1},
              {row:origin.row+1,col:origin.col+1}
            ];
      } else if (shape === 'I90') {
          return [
              {row:origin.row,col:origin.col},
              {row:origin.row,col:origin.col-1},
              {row:origin.row,col:origin.col+1},
              {row:origin.row,col:origin.col+2}
            ];
      } else if (shape === 'S90') {
          return [
              {row:origin.row,col:origin.col},
              {row:origin.row-1,col:origin.col},
              {row:origin.row-1,col:origin.col-1},
              {row:origin.row-2,col:origin.col-1}
            ];
      } else if (shape === 'Z90') {
          return [
              {row:origin.row,col:origin.col},
              {row:origin.row-1,col:origin.col},
              {row:origin.row-1,col:origin.col+1},
              {row:origin.row-2,col:origin.col+1}
            ];
      } else if (shape === 'T90') {
          return [
              {row:origin.row,col:origin.col},
              {row:origin.row-1,col:origin.col},
              {row:origin.row+1,col:origin.col},
              {row:origin.row,col:origin.col+1}
            ];
      } else if (shape === 'T180') {
          return [
              {row:origin.row,col:origin.col},
              {row:origin.row+1,col:origin.col},
              {row:origin.row,col:origin.col-1},
              {row:origin.row,col:origin.col+1}
            ];
      } else if (shape === 'T270') {
          return [
              {row:origin.row,col:origin.col},
              {row:origin.row-1,col:origin.col},
              {row:origin.row+1,col:origin.col},
              {row:origin.row,col:origin.col-1}
            ];
      } 
}

//Filling the cells
tetris.fillCells = function(coordinates, fillColor) {
    for (let i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
        let row = coordinates[i].row;
        let col = coordinates[i].col;
        let $coor = $('.'+row).find('#'+col);
        $coor.attr('bgcolor', fillColor);
    }
}


// Moving the object right/left
tetris.move = function(direction) {
    this.fillCells(this.currentCoordinates, '');

    // Moving origin
    if (direction === 'right') {
        this.origin.col++;
    } else if (direction === 'left') {
        this.origin.col--;
    } 

    this.currentCoordinates = this.shapeToCoordinates(this.currentShape, this.origin);

    if (this.ifReverse()) {
        if (direction === 'right') {
            this.origin.col--;
        } else if (direction === 'left') {
            this.origin.col++
        }
    }

    this.currentCoordinates = this.shapeToCoordinates(this.currentShape, this.origin);

    this.fillCells(this.currentCoordinates, 'red');

}

// Rotating our shapes
tetris.rotate = function() {
    let lastShape = this.currentShape;
    this.fillCells(this.currentCoordinates,'');

    if (this.currentShape === 'L') {
        this.currentShape = 'L90';
    } else if (this.currentShape === 'L90') {
        this.currentShape = 'L180';
    } else if (this.currentShape === 'L180') {
        this.currentShape = 'L270';
    } else if (this.currentShape === 'L270') {
        this.currentShape = 'L';
    } else if (this.currentShape === 'J') {
        this.currentShape = 'J90';
    } else if (this.currentShape === 'J90') {
        this.currentShape = 'J180';
    } else if (this.currentShape === 'J180') {
        this.currentShape = 'J270';
    } else if (this.currentShape === 'J270') {
        this.currentShape = 'J';
    } else if (this.currentShape === 'I') {
        this.currentShape = 'I90';
    } else if (this.currentShape === 'I90') {
        this.currentShape = 'I';
    } else if (this.currentShape === 'S') {
        this.currentShape = 'S90';
    } else if (this.currentShape === 'S90') {
        this.currentShape = 'S';
    } else if (this.currentShape === 'Z') {
        this.currentShape = 'Z90';
    } else if (this.currentShape === 'Z90') {
        this.currentShape = 'Z';
    } else if (this.currentShape === 'T') {
        this.currentShape = 'T90';
    } else if(this.currentShape === 'T90') {
        this.currentShape = 'T180';
    } else if (this.currentShape === 'T180') {
        this.currentShape = 'T270';
    } else if (this.currentShape === 'T270') {
        this.currentShape = 'T';
    }

    this.currentCoordinates = this.shapeToCoordinates(this.currentShape, this.origin);

    for (let i = 0; i < this.currentCoordinates.length; i++) {
        if (this.ifReverse()) {
            this.currentShape = lastShape;
        }
    }

    this.currentCoordinates = this.shapeToCoordinates(this.currentShape, this.origin);
    this.fillCells(this.currentCoordinates, 'red');
}

// Moving shapes down (adding gravity)
tetris.drop = function() {
    let reverse = false;

    this.fillCells(this.currentCoordinates, '');
    this.origin.row++;

    for (let i = 0; i < this.currentCoordinates.length; i++) {
        this.currentCoordinates[i].row++;
        if (this.ifReverse()) {   
                reverse = true;
        }
    }

    if (reverse) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.currentCoordinates.length; i++) {
            this.currentCoordinates[i].row--;
        }
        this.origin.row--;
    }

    this.fillCells(this.currentCoordinates, 'red');

    if (reverse) {
        this.fillCells(this.currentCoordinates, 'RED');
        this.emptyFullRow();
        this.spawn();
        // console.log(this.currentCoordinates)
    }

    this.gameIsOver()
}

// If we need to reverse the shape (when shape reach the bottom/reach other shape)
tetris.ifReverse = function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.currentCoordinates.length; i++) {
        let row = this.currentCoordinates[i].row;
        let col = this.currentCoordinates[i].col;
        let $coor = $('.'+row).find('#'+col);

        if ($coor.length === 0 || $coor.attr('bgcolor') === 'RED') {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Empty the full row
tetris.emptyFullRow = function() {
    let drops = 0; // store the number of full rows

    for (let i = 21; i >= 0; i--) { // scan rows from the bottom to the top
        let rowIsFull = true;

        for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) { // scan columns from left to right
            let $coor = $('.'+i).find('#'+j);

            if ($coor.attr('bgcolor') !== 'RED') {
                rowIsFull = false;
            }

            if (drops > 0) {
                let $newCoor = $('.'+ (i + drops)).find('#'+j); // referencing the cell lower by the number of rows stored in drops
                $newCoor.attr('bgcolor', $coor.attr('bgcolor')); 
            }
        }

        if (rowIsFull) {
            drops++;
        }
    }
}

// Spawning a random shape
tetris.spawn = function() {
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
    let shapeArray = ['L', 'J', 'I', 'O', 'S', 'T', 'Z'];

    this.currentShape = shapeArray[random];
    this.origin = {row: 1, col: 5};
    this.currentCoordinates = this.shapeToCoordinates(this.currentShape, this.origin);
}

tetris.gameIsOver = function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.currentCoordinates.length; i++) {
        let row = this.currentCoordinates[i].row;
        let col = this.currentCoordinates[i].col;
        let $coor = $('.'+row).find('#'+col);
        if (row === 0 && $coor.attr('bgcolor') === 'RED') {
            console.log(this.currentCoordinates)
            alert('Game is over. Please, refresh the page to start again');

        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    tetris.drawPlayField();
    tetris.currentCoordinates = tetris.shapeToCoordinates(tetris.currentShape, tetris.origin);
    tetris.spawn();
    tetris.fillCells(tetris.currentCoordinates, 'red');

    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 39) {
            tetris.move('right');
        } else if (e.keyCode === 37) {
            tetris.move('left');
        } else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
            tetris.rotate();
        } else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
            tetris.drop();
        }
    })

    let gravity = setInterval(function() {
        tetris.drop();
    }, 500);

})
```

Comment: I notices that you are using setInteval to call the method drop() over and over again. This means, each time your method gameIsOver() is being called; therefore, you will see the alert, with the Game Over message, to show over and over again. You may want to implement a some short of state flag OR take a look into State Pattern in JavaScript.

Comment: The problem happens when you spawn some shape which have some parts in a first row (such as I shape). Then you call a `gameIsOver` to check the first row which it has.

Comment: The shape that is spawning is quite different from the one that is laying on another shape. They have different `bgcolor` attribute. New shape - 'red', shape that has been dropped - 'RED'